# JList repeatedly updating defaultlistmodel after selecting item 0

Tags: java, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel, listselectionlistener

I am using the Swing designer in Eclipse to build a GUI to list my movies which are stored in an XML file. After loading the frame and contents to the various `JList`s, I have the app set to update the lists when an item is selected. So, if you pick a genre, all the movies for that genre will be shown, same applies for groups, episodes and seasons. I also have a refresh lists button which reloads the lists.

the problem I am encountering is: when I have selected the item at index `0`, an extra listener action is called compared to when I select index `1` or higher. Then (my main concern), if I select the refresh button, a listener is fired for every item added to the `listmodel` for the previously selected `JList`.

For example, if I select `1` from the episodes list & then refresh, only 1 listener is called. However, if I select `0` from the episode list & then refresh, I get 35 listeners called (which is the total amount of episodes in the list).

For something small like the episodes this isn't a big issue, but when this happens on the movies column I get around 1500 listeners fired.

```
package local.testarea;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

@SuppressWarnings( { "rawtypes", "unchecked" } )
public class ListDemo {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JList list, list_1;
    private JButton btnNewButton;
    private DefaultListModel<String> list2;
    private DefaultListModel<Integer> list1;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable() {

            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    ListDemo window = new ListDemo();
                    window.frame.setVisible( true );
                }
                catch ( Exception e )
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } );
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public ListDemo()
    {
        list1 = new DefaultListModel<Integer>();
        list2 = new DefaultListModel<String>();
        initialize();
        updateAll();
    }

    private void updateAll()
    {
        list1.clear();
        list2.clear();
        for ( int i = 0; i < 101; i++ )
        {
            list1.addElement( i );
        }
        list2.addElement( "Even" );
        list2.addElement( "Odd" );

    }

    private void updateLists( int selected )
    {
        list1.clear();
        list2.clear();
        switch( selected )
        {
            case 0:
                for ( int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
                {
                    if ( i % 2 == 0 ) 
                    {
                        list1.addElement( i );
                    }
                }
                list2.addElement( "Even" );
                break;

            case 1:
                for ( int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
                {
                    if ( i % 2 != 0 ) 
                    {
                        list1.addElement( i );
                    }
                }
                list2.addElement( "Odd" );
                break;

            default:
                int z = selected - 10;
                list1.addElement( z );
                list2.addElement( "Even" );
                list2.addElement( "Odd" );
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds( 100, 100, 450, 481 );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[grow][grow]", "[grow][]"));

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, "cell 0 0,grow");

        list = new JList( list1 );
        list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                System.out.println( "List 1 trigger" );
                System.out.println( "selected item: " + list_1.getSelectedIndex() );
                if ( list.getSelectedIndex() >= 0 )
                {
                    int z = 10 + list.getSelectedIndex();
                    updateLists( z );
                }
            }
        });
        scrollPane.setViewportView(list);

        JScrollPane scrollPane_1 = new JScrollPane();
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane_1, "cell 1 0,grow");

        list_1 = new JList( list2 );
        list_1.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                System.out.println( "List 2 trigger" );
                System.out.println( "selected item: " + list_1.getSelectedIndex() );
                if ( list_1.getSelectedIndex() >= 0 )
                {
                    updateLists( list_1.getSelectedIndex() );
                }
            }
        });
        scrollPane_1.setViewportView(list_1);

        btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println( "refresh" );
                updateAll();
            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton, "cell 1 1");
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: @APW Please create an example which uses only standard java classes, so we can run it to reproduce your problem. I have neither class Video, nor VideoProvider, nor ItemToUpdate. I know about MigLayout, but don't have it in my class path.

Comment: Don't understand your code completely, but my guess is that it's got something to do with setLists. If anywhere you're adding "everything" back into your list model again, like for a refresh, you'll trip the listener once for each item added.

Comment: I have swapped the code for a new version that runs into exactly the same issues with the 0 index refresh.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy There are only 3 components added. I just removed the `setLayout` line. With that being said, @APW should still fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying the lists while selection is still in progress, which causes additional selection events to be fired (recursively). You are also modifying both lists for no reason.

The `String` list should just act as a filter to the `Integer` List. Also, I don't understand why you're removing all the items from the `Integer` list when a single value is selected. It makes it look like a `JList` is not what you want to use.

In any case, I modified your `ListSelectionListener`:

```
public class ListDemo extends JFrame{

    private DefaultListModel<Integer> listModel1 = new DefaultListModel<>();
    private DefaultListModel<String> listModel2 = new DefaultListModel<>();
    private JList<Integer> list1 = new JList<>(listModel1);
    private JList<String> list2 = new JList<>(listModel2);
    int size = 101;

    public ListDemo() {

        list1.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        add(new JScrollPane(list1));

        list2.addListSelectionListener(new ListParityFilter());
        list2.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        listModel2.addElement("All");
        listModel2.addElement("Even");
        listModel2.addElement("Odd");
        list2.setSelectedIndex(0);
        add(new JScrollPane(list2), BorderLayout.EAST);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private class ListParityFilter implements ListSelectionListener {

        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

            if (e.getValueIsAdjusting())
                return;
            System.out.println("Selected List2 item: " + list2.getSelectedValue());
            listModel1.clear();
            switch (list2.getSelectedIndex()) {
                case 0:
                    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                        listModel1.addElement(i);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 2)
                        listModel1.addElement(i);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    for (int i = 1; i < size; i += 2)
                        listModel1.addElement(i);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new ListDemo();
    }
}
```

#### Notes:

- Instead of the refresh button, I added an "All" option for the filter list.
- The filter list should not be modified (there is no reason).
- Check for `e.getValueIsAdjusting()` so you don't perform unnecessary operations.
- I set the selection model to `SINGLE_SELECTION` for both lists.
- I removed the `Integer` list selection listener because it serves no purpose. It will be called *once* in 2 situations:

  1. When a value is selected (selected index >= 0).
  2. When a filter is applied, since the list is cleared (selected index = -1).
- Use `pack()` on the `JFrame` instead of setting its size and location.

Comment: That seems to resolve my issues. The integer list is a placeholder for a list of movie names. If you think a Jlist is a poor choice what would you recommend? I have been using a button because I have been refreshing 4 different lists at once, but I do see the benefit of an All of option in the lists. Thank you.

Comment: @APW I don't think it's a poor choice the way I use it. A `JList` is supposed to show a list of items from which you can select one (or more) item(s). The selection highlights the item and keeps the other items visible. You don't utilize that, you just remove all the unselected items, which made me think about what exactly you're trying to do with the list. I don't know what other lists you have, so I can't recommend a refresh button.

Comment: Thank you that's actually a more helpful answer than you may realise. I have 4 lists that depending on their order will modify the remaining unselected lists. I was previously just running a method that refreshed all 4 lists at once, but I now realise why it is better to set it up to only refresh the unselected lists. This app has been a steep rewarding learning curve for me, I've only been writing Java for 6months :-)

Comment: @APW I don't think you need to refresh anything. Just add an unfiltered option for all the filters, like the "All" option.